# Sign of infinity on division by zero

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I've implemented code to find the polar coordinates of a point in 2D space. if the point lies in the 1st or 2nd Quadrant, `0<=theta<=pi` and if it lies in the 3rd or 4th Quadrant, `-pi <= theta <= 0`.

```
      module thetalib

      contains 
      real function comp_theta( x1, x2)
      implicit none

      real        , intent(in)    :: x1, x2
      real                        :: x1p, x2p
      real                        :: x1_c=0.0, x2_c=0.0
      real                        :: pi=4*atan(1.0)

      x1p = x1 - x1_c
      x2p = x2 - x2_c

!  - Patch
      !if ( x1p == 0 .and. x2p /= 0 ) then
      !   comp_theta = sign(pi/2.0, x2p)
      !else
      !   comp_theta = atan ( x2p / x1p )
      !endif

      comp_theta = atan( x2p / x1p)

      if ( x1p >= 0.0 .and. x2p >= 0.0 ) then
         comp_theta = comp_theta
      elseif ( x1p < 0 .and. x2p >= 0.0 ) then
         comp_theta = pi + comp_theta
      elseif( x1p < 0.0 .and. x2p < 0.0 ) then
         comp_theta = -1* (pi - comp_theta)
      elseif ( x1p >= 0.0 .and. x2p < 0.0 ) then
         comp_theta = comp_theta
      endif

      return
      end function comp_theta

      end module thetalib

      program main

      use thetalib

      implicit none

!     Quadrant 1
      print *, "(0.00, 1.00): ", comp_theta(0.00, 1.00)
      print *, "(1.00, 0.00): ", comp_theta(1.00, 0.00)
      print *, "(1.00, 1.00): ", comp_theta(1.00, 1.00)

!     Quadrant 2
      print *, "(-1.00, 1.00): ", comp_theta(-1.00, 1.00)
      print *, "(-1.00, 0.00): ", comp_theta(-1.00, 0.00)

!     Quadrant 3
      print *, "(-1.00, -1.00): ", comp_theta(-1.00, -1.00)


!     Quadrant 4
      print *, "(0.00, -1.00): ", comp_theta(0.00, -1.00)
      print *, "(1.00, -1.00): ", comp_theta(1.00, -1.00)

      end program main
```

In the function `thetalib::comp_theta`, when there is a division by zero and the numerator is +ve, fortran evaluates it to be `-infinity` and when the numerator is -ve, it evaluates it to be `+infinity` ( see output )

```
 (0.00, 1.00):   -1.570796    
 (1.00, 0.00):   0.0000000E+00
 (1.00, 1.00):   0.7853982    
 (-1.00, 1.00):    2.356194    
 (-1.00, 0.00):    3.141593    
 (-1.00, -1.00):   -2.356194    
 (0.00, -1.00):    1.570796    
 (1.00, -1.00):  -0.7853982
```

This baffled me. I've also implemented the patch you see to work around it. And to investigate it further, I setup a small test:

```
  program main

  implicit none

  real          :: x1, x2

  x1 = 0.0 - 0.0 ! Reflecting the x1p - 0.0
  x2 = 1.0

  write(*,*) "x2/x1=", x2/x1

  x2 = -1.0
  write(*,*) "x2/x1=", x2/x1

  end program main
```

This evaluates to:

```
 x2/x1=       Infinity
 x2/x1=      -Infinity
```

My fortran version:

```
$ ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 19.0.1.144 20181018
Copyright (C) 1985-2018 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

And I have three questions:

1. Why there are signed infinite values?
2. How are the signs determined?
3. Why does `infinity` take the signs shown in outputs for both `thetalib::comp_theta` and the test program?

Comment: Won't it be easier to use the `atan2(y,x)` function than to spin you own?

Comment: @Steve yeah definitely for this particular case but I'd like to know why the signs don't match.

Comment: Are you asking why there are signed infinite values, why each is the result in the short test, or how to avoid them?

Comment: @francescalus yes, (a) why there are signed infinite values? (b) how the signs are determined - both in the short test case as well as `thetalib::comp_theta`?How to avoid would follow from the answers to (a) and (b). Will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 I try replicating it with the test program in the line `x1 = 0.0 - 0.0` but with different results. Limits was the first thing which crossed my mind too but I wasn't able to reproduce it.

Comment: You can also try checking if the number equals itself. if not then. it is infinite.  EX: `if ( x2x1 .eq. x2x1)` then GOOD number. if not then infinity.  It also may be that the value holding x1 is calculated by the computer where all bits in the number are set to 1 (-infinity) and simply dividing 1/(allbits =1) => changes the sign bit of the value to -infinity. same for -1/(allbits=1) changes sign bit to +Infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That there are signed infinite values follows from the compiler supporting IEEE arithmetic with the real type.

For motivation, consider real non-zero numerator and denominator.  If these are both of the same sign then the quotient is a real (finite) positive number.  If they are of opposite sign the quotient is a real (finite) negative number.

Consider the limit `1/x` as x tends to zero from below.  For any strictly negative value of `x` the value is negative.  For continuity considerations the limit can be taken to be negative infinity.

So, when the numerator is non-zero, the quotient will be positive infinity if the numerator and denominator are of the same sign, and negative if of opposite sign.  Recall also, that the zero denominator [may be signed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53086414/3157076).

If you wish to examine the number, to see whether it is finite you can use the procedure `IEEE_IS_FINITE` of the intrinsic module `ieee_arithmetic`.  Further, that module has the procedure `IEEE_CLASS` which provides useful information about its argument.  Among other things:

- whether it is a positive or negative *normal* number;
- whether it is a positive or negative infinite value;
- whether it is a positive or negative zero.

Comment: This in conjunction with @IAmNerd2000's answer clarifies all parts of the question asked. Is there a way to merge the two?

Comment: @newkid Now you see why you should ask one question per post here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try checking if the number equals itself. if not then. it is infinite.

EX: `if ( x2x1 .eq. x2x1)` then GOOD number. if not then infinity.

It also may be that the value holding x1 is calculated by the computer where all bits in the number are set to 1 (-infinity) and doing a bitwise divide you get the following:

which, is actually a subtraction operation where (0....001 - 01...111) = -Infinity
 and (0....001 - 11.....111) = +Infinity I would look up bitwise divide and see the info on that.  More is done, but I don't need to explain the details.

Comment: This explains a part of the answer i.e. the output in the test program which is already very nice. Thanks! Any ideas on what happens in the function  `comp_theta` ?

Comment: I notice that you have the following  `x1p < 0` in your elseif statement when it should be  `x1p < 0.0` otherwise it is evaluating x1p as an integer